# Unable to access register data from Siemens S7 200 Smart PLC from Raspberry pi 4 using python script and Profibus communication between two?

Tags: raspberry-pi, siemens

I am trying to read and write data on Siemens S7 200 SMART PLC from Raspberry pi 4 having bullseye debian os but I am unable to do it with Profibus Please share reference if any or suggestions.

I have tried below things but encountered issues,

https://pypi.org/project/pyprofibus/

above is the link to library I used for communication. also added GSD file to it but unable to RUN,
Also, I tried to search for GSD file for Raspberry pi 4 but could not find please help.